# How to define a constraint using IloColumn and IloRange?

Tags: java, cplex

I have a constraint in my model and I want to use `Ilocolumn` and `IloRange` to write that in java using Cplex. Could anyone please help me? The constraint is given below:

```
sum over k (y_k) <= 500;
```

Here, `y_k` is the decision variable and `k` is a set. I have created the column for my decision variable. I just don't know how to associate it with the constraint.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want or need to use IloColumn for modelling? If you look at the Java examples provided with CPLEX, it is more common to just use IloNumVars and that seems to be a natural way to proceed.

Comment: Yes. I am trying to implement column generation in my code and this way seems to be the most appropriate to me.